# Child ScrollBar for individual controls inside parent Scrollbar

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a view which has Two Group boxes. 
The first Group box contains fields which would occupy the 75% of the screen in a normal scenario. The rest of the screen is occupied by the remarks groupbox.
The "Remarks" groupbox contains a textbox which is allowing multiline entry for the user.
I would like to disable the scrolling in GroupBox2 (Remarks GroupBox) and let the Textbox deal with the scroll bar inside it .if the user enters more text.

Here is my code.

```
<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                               
         <GroupBox Header ="General">
             <!--Lot of Fields here-->
         </GroupBox> 
         <GroupBox Header ="Remarks">
             <Textbox AcceptsReturn=true MinHeight =60/>
         </GroupBox>
     </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Currently when i enter more values in the textbox , the textbox size is increasing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the groupbox height and set the height of textbox to actual height of groupbox using below code.

```
<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Header ="General">
            <!--Lot of Fields here-->
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="GB2" Header ="Remarks" Height="200">
            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"  Height="{Binding ElementName=GB2,Path=ActualHeight}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```